# asynchronous form of Beep()

Tags: c++, winapi

I have tried `Beep()` on my computer and it works as expected. I need an asynchronous form which allows me to turn on the speaker with a tone of a given frequency and while it is sounding allow me to run other code. I should be able to change frequencies at will and shut it off with a zero argument.
i.e

```
tone(freq1); // start sounding at freq1
// execute other code which will use time and decide tone length
tone(freq2); // a new tone at freq2
// execute more work
tone(0); // turn off sound
```

Since `Beep()` works on my machine, I expect this function is also available.

I am trying to replicate an old program which programmed the speaker hardware directly.

Working in C++, Win7 VS2013. Writing a Windows based program with OpenGL.

Comment: Ae you looking for a somewhat portable solution, or does it only ever have to work on your box?

Comment: I expect that the code will run on any W7 box.

Comment: If Beep(frequency, duration) runs this should also run.

Comment: The waveOut*() win32 API (waveOutOpen()/waveOutPrepareHeader()/waveOutWrite()/etc) can be made to do what you want; you'd need to generate the samples using sin() or cos() and then push them out to the audio system on schedule.  I don't know if there is anything more specific than that.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. In view of the fact that Beep() is so easy to use this seems like a obvious hole in the library. If I could get at the Beep() code I could decimate it down to what I want.

Comment: _"If I could get at the Beep() code"_ -- [yes you can](https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/c6d2b35ffc91e09f50dfb214ea58237509329d6b/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/file/deviceio.c#L48). Granted, it's not the original. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread that can call `Beep()` and use one of the many ways to communicate with it, such as `SendMessage()`.

But as far as your solution can go, `Beep()` is not responsive if you want it to be so.

Comment: I am trying to coordinate the tone changes with a graphic program clocked

Comment: Are you willing to only use the Windows API or are you open to other libraries?

Comment: This is a home project. I am not looking to buy something. I am willing to try another library. Everything I have found so far involves setting up wav files. I think this is vast overkill to be able to write two bytes to a sound chip.